Macro to return 1 + the value of the cell above
I am experienced with VBA but not Google Apps Script / Javascript.
I'm doing a lot of data entry for which filling down with CTRL+D is super-useful but I want to create a macro that will copy down the value from the row above while also adding 1.
I've had a few attempts and I can't get it to work.
So far, I have only successfully achieved it by the rather obtuse two-step method of copying down with CTRL+D followed by this code to increment the value:
  var c = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getCurrentCell();
  c.setValue(c.getValue()+1);

How do I get the value of the cell above and add 1 to it in a single step?

Macro
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function myFunction() {
  const cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getCurrentCell();
  cell.setValue(cell.offset(-1, 0).getValue()+1);
  cell.offset(0, 1).activate();
}


Sets the current cell's value to 1 plus the value of the cell that is offset -1 rows and 0 columns (directly above it).
Activates the cell that is offset 0 rows and 1 column from the current cell (directly to the right).

Running Macro
Use either of the following approaches.

Set up a keyboard shortcut using Ctrl+Alt+Shift+[0-9].  You select the specific digit when you first setup the Macro or you can set it up or modify it in the Manage macros section.  Access it at:
  →  Menu:        Extensions > Macros > Manage macros
  →  Keyboard:  Alt+Shift+N M M
Run the macro directly from the menu:
  →  Menu:        Extensions > Macros > Your_macro_name
  →  Keyboard:  Alt+Shift+N M ▼ ▼ Enter
       If the macro is not 1st in the list you'll need more down arrows


Thanks. This does almost achieve what I wanted to do, but it still leaves a formula in the cell rather than a value, which for various reasons is not suitable for my needs. Your suggestion of CTRL+C then CTRL+SHIFT+V will of course convert the formula to its value, but I am trying to find a way to have the macro write the incremented value (rather than to formula) to the cell in the first place.

@DanielAustin answer has been modified to return a value instead of a formula.
